# How to return XML as separate values using XDocument and XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am trying to get values from an XML document using XDocument and XElement. I am trying to get three values, however when I try to return them, they are merged together as one value. Here is the XML I am searching:

```
<create_maint_traveler>     
<Paths>
        <outputPath value="D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\DataInput\MCDHeaderDrop\" />
        <outputPath_today value="D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\DataInput\Today\" />
        <log value="D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\Log\CreateMaintLog.log" />
    </Paths>
</create_maint_traveler>
```

Here is how I am querying the values:

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load(XML);
            foreach (XElement node in config.Root.Elements("Paths"))
            {
                if (node.Name == "outputPath") outputPath = node.Value;
                if (node.Name == "outputPath_today") outputPath = node.Value;
                if (node.Name == "log") outputPath = node.Value;
            }
```

When I output to a file, i find that the returned value is

```
D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\DataInput\MCDHeaderDrop\D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\DataInput\Today\D:\Intercim\DNC_Share\itcm\Log\CreateMaintLog.log
```

Or there will be nothing returned. I had the values in the XML file outside of the tags before which returned the one long value. I  am confused about how to return the outputPath, outputPath_today and log values seperatly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown what you're returning at all. (It's not clear why you don't just *ask* for those values, either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(XML);
var paths = xDoc.Root.Elements("Paths");

var res = from p in paths
          select new
                     {
                         outputPath = p.Element("outputPath").Attribute("value").Value,
                         outputPath_today = p.Element("outputPath_today").Attribute("value").Value,
                         log = p.Element("log").Attribute("value").Value
                    };

 foreach(path in res)
 {
      System.Console.WriteLine(path.outputPath);
      System.Console.WriteLine(path.outputPath_today);
      System.Console.WriteLine(path.log);
      // or do anything you want to do with those properties
 }
```

You will get values of `outputPath`, `outputPath_today` and `log` into an `IEnumerable` of anonymous objects. These objects each will have property `outputPath`, `outputPath_today` and `log` with values populated from XML.